# how to specify jsp file upload storage folder path dynamically in server

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlet-3.0

i wrote file upload programme in jsp in elipse id using `cos.jar` described in this  [link](http://webideaworld.blogspot.in/2013/04/woking-with-enctypemultipartform-data.html)
i got desired output.

-> now i want to specify the path folder to store image in server to be dynamic, because if this path is fixed type to particular directory in the server  **my project won't be portable**, how to get rid of this.

path given in servlet is as follows :

```
MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"E:/workspace/fileUpload/WebContent/uploads/");
```

want to know if there exists any regular expressions or some alternate method like :
**${project_path}** and also like to know how to Validate uploads using `Java scripts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we deploy any web application on server.There is a path something like

```
http://<host>:<port>/<contextPath>
```

this to access that deployed webapp.

Now you can set some specific folder in that live web directory where you can save image dynamically.Now with this [Get Realpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) you can get realpath of your webapp and then append your specified folder's path with that realpath you can save your images so that it will be independent from static path.

Suppose as a example:

I have one application ABC and deployed on **http://www.xyz.com/ABC/** (Context path of deployed webapp). Now in database or in property file or in code I specified one folder named as **profilepics** in war file.In my method I will get realpath(context path) and append that folder name so path is like **http://www.xyz.com/ABC/profilepics/** which store images uploaded by user.Donlt forget to add security to that folder if content stored in that directory is confidential.

Comment: You can get the realpath by code shown in given link.

Comment: thank u for ur kind replay... info was useful, best regards mr.Satyam Koyani

Comment: @user3090315 Your walm welcome on stackoverflow.Make habit to accept the answer, if it solved your problem.